# How do I keep this program going until they say no

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ("Welcome to my Break-even calculator")
FC = input("Please enter your fixed costs ")
SP = input("Please enter your Selling Price (per item) ")
VC = input("Please enter your Variable costs (per item) ")
A = float(SP) - float(VC)
BE = float(FC) / A
print("Your Break-even point is ",BE)
B = input("Would you like to go again y/n? ")
while B not in ['y','n']:
    print("INVALID RESPONCE")
    B = input("Would you like to go again y/n? ")
if B == ("y"):
    FC = input("Please enter your fixed costs ")
    SP = input("Please enter your Selling Price (per item) ")
    VC = input("Please enter your Variable costs (per item) ")
    A = float(SP) - float(VC)
    BE = float(FC) / A
    print("Your Break-even point is ", BE)
    B = input("Would you like to go again y/n? ")
else:
    finished = True
```

Im in school and i cant be bothered to do the calculations every time so i wrote this but i cant get it to repeat more than twice so i am wondering what i need to change to get it to work so any help will be nice.

Comment: Change your `if` to a `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the program run indefinitely (well, until they say no) the neatest way possible: use a while loop:

```
running = True

while running:
    [all your code here]
```

And then, when the user says "n", you can do the following:

```
if B (your yes/no var?) == 'n':
    running = False
```

This would immediately stop the while loop. Hope this helps.